# Using .contains on custom type array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to find out if an array of a custom type contains that custom type in a 2D array, but am getting this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Modifier' to expected argument type '(Modifier) throws -> Bool'`

Not sure what is going wrong in this code:

```
for x in 0..<tableDataSource.count {
    for i in 0..<tableDataSource[x].count {
        if(existingModifiers.contains(where: tableDataSource[x][i].mod)){
            tableDataSource[x][i].selected = true
        }
    }
}
```

existingModifiers is an array of type `Modifier`
and tableDataSource is a 2D array of type `tableElement`
where `tableElement` contains a `Modifier` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
if(existingModifiers.contains(where: tableDataSource[x][i].mod))
```

with:

```
if(existingModifiers.contains(where: { $0 == tableDataSource[x][i].mod }))
```

---

**Note**

In Swift you can omit parentheses in `if` statements for better clarity:

```
if existingModifiers.contains(where: { $0 == tableDataSource[x][i].mod })
```

Comment: that gives me this error  ```Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Modifier' operands```

Comment: @NoahIarrobino In that case you need to conform `Modifier` to `Equatable`. See [How to conform to the Equatable protocol](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-conform-to-the-equatable-protocol)